# Stemming Geographical words

Tags: python, text, nlp, nltk, text-processing

What is the best stemming method to geographical entities? I want to convert the geographical entities gathered in a dataframe column to accurate region names like for example converting:

```
['India','Indian','Japanese','Europe','European']
```

to

```
['India','India','Japan','Europe','Europe']
```

The geographical words will be extracted from more than 50,000 news, so I'm looking for a function which could work critical situations.

Comment: What about a lookup table? A dictionary maybe. Could you maybe give more details to clarify what the problem is?

Comment: Sure.

The problem is - I have extracted some geographical entities from the description of 300 news, and now I have ended up with some lists like 'list' mentioned above in a dataframe column. Here, I want to clean and process the above similar lists ahead so that I could get accurate region names.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Ideally it would be part of the question body itself. I still don't really understand what makes this a NLP problem. You seem to have already identified the geographical terms and put them in a list and the list cannot be that long if there are only 300 news. Why not doing it manually?

Comment: Thanks @Trilarion for replying back.

I know it has already identified geographical words. But for the words like - 'Japanese', 'European', 'American'. I want to get the words - 'Japan','Europe','America'.

Coming to 300 news, why not doing it manually. Initially, for testing I have taken only 300 news. But I have news more than 50000 where I would like to test later. So, bacically I am looking for a function which could work critical situations.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. All these explanations should be part of the question instead of being comments. I edited the question to show you and upvoted because I think that it is a good question now. I hope you get an answer, unfortunately I don't know the answer. I wonder though if you might also get some ideas by asking that on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks @Trilarion for editing the question and upvoting. Hope I get a solution for the same soon.